# Non-unitarity of wave function collapse

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction-collapse

Why the wave function collapse corresponds to a non-unitary quantum operation?

Comment: My question arose from this statement: "A general description of the evolution of quantum mechanical systems is possible by using density operators and quantum operations. In this formalism (which is closely related to the C*-algebraic formalism) the collapse of the wave function corresponds to a non-unitary quantum operation."                                                          http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave_function_collapse

Answer (score 5):

Unitary operators are operators that satisfy some conditions. Among other things, they have to be linear:

> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unitary_operator

The operation (or "an operation") that maps any $\psi(x)$ to $\delta(x-x_0)$ where $x_0$ is the random position resulting from a measurement can't be associated with any linear operator. It's easy to see why. Take two functions $\psi_1(x)$ and $\psi_2(x)$ that have different supports: for example, the first one is localized in the vicinity of Boston while the other sits near New York.

Linearity of the collapse operator $C$ requires
$$ C (\psi_1 + \psi_2) = C(\psi_1) + C(\psi_2).$$
However, the first term of the right hand side is a delta-function localized somewhere near Boston while the second term of the right hand side is a delta-function localized near New York. Their sum therefore can't be a multiple of a single delta-function, so the left hand side can't be a "collapsed wave function", proving that an operator that maps anything to a single delta-function can't be linear.

There are of course other ways to prove that it can't be a unitary operator – which is a very strong condition.

Of course, the right resolution of this non-unitarity problem is that there's nothing such as the collapse of a wave function. The wave function is not a real wave: it's a set of complex amplitudes whose squared absolute values don't describe "the reality" but rather just the probabilities of "different realities". The probability distributions *mean* that you always get just one outcome and the values of the probability distribution just tell you what the probabilities of different outcomes are. Nothing has to "collapse" because the wave wasn't a "real observable wave" to start with.

The idea that the wave function has to *"collapse"* and one has to look for a *"mechanism"* how it collapses is an artifact of a misinterpretation of the wave function.

Comment: Hi Lubos, I don't believe in the validity of this interpretation of measurement as a merely notational artifact; intermediate measurements make probabilities behave different. Collapse, be it an effective result of complex phenomena or something fundamental, it is a real process. In any case, even if measurements are not linear and hence non-unitary by the book definition, *they still conserve the norm of eigenstates*

Comment: Dear @lurscher, the fact that the wave function is just a set of numbers to calculate probabilities from, and not a real observable, is an experimentally proven fact, not a matter for beliefs or disbeliefs. By the way, your second statement is also impossible. One can't define a prescription for such a collapse so that it would conserve the norm if we also require the physics to be local: one has to artificially "renormalize" the wave function after the collapse and it's clearly a non-local procedure because it depends on the magnitude of the wave function at other "places".

Comment: Dear @ANKU, I don't know how you proved that the inner product of $C\psi_i$ and $C\psi_j$ is the particular Kronecker-delta. I think that there's no operator that would satisfy your condition for every $\psi_i$, $\psi_j$. Moreover, I don't understand what's the difference between $\psi_j$ and $j$. What you wrote is just very confusing.

Comment: @Lurscher, let me also mention that if you want the post-collapse wave function to be proportional to a delta-function in the position representation, such an outcome would 1) have a very sick normalization because you need $\psi(x)=\sqrt{\delta(x-x_0)}$ for the squared wave function to have the right integral; the square root of a delta function isn't really an element of the Hilbert space; 2) if the wave function is strictly proportional to the delta-function, it carries an infinite average kinetic energy: the momentum is totally undetermined and the expectation value of $p^2$ diverges.

Comment: @lubos, regarding non-locality; measurements in the most basic formulation given in QM courses always assume that you are able to measure the state in a non-local way. To be more physically realistic, you need to understand that your measurement actually doesn't discriminate between far-away states, it just gives you a range of projection operators for local positions near the range of the measurement apparatus. In all these cases, the "renormalize" step is just taking the norm of the part of the state function that is in the range.

Comment: @Lubos, yes, square roots of deltas are not well defined (neither are squared deltas), but all test functions that approach a delta do have it, that is not a problem if you assume there is a cutoff length. By construction, a physical state is always normalized. The fact that measurements are described a posteriori from the process doesn't alter the fact that they preserve the norm of the state vector trivially by the fact that by convention a state vector will always have unit norm.

Comment: However, if the measurement is part of a complex process with multiple observers, then you will not in general apply a normalization, because this normalization is only valid in a global state, never on individual parts of the system

Comment: "measurements in the most basic formulation given in QM courses always assume that you are able to measure the state in a non-local way" - Nope, there is no contradiction between locality and the postulates of quantum mechanics, as demonstrated by the important example of local quantum field theories such as the Standard Model which are perfectly local. They also describe reality: all physical processes in this Universe are demonstrably local, which proves that all mechanisms that are nonlocal are unphysical.

Comment: @lurscher This is kind of off topic, but for what it's worth, you *can* define the square of the delta function.  In fact, you can define the product of any two tempered distributions as the Fourier transform of their convolution (which can be defined directly).  I have a feeling that you can also make precise sense out of the square-root of a nonnegative tempered distribution, but I'd have to think about how to do that.

Comment: Dear @Jonathan, in some modest sense, you may be able to "define" the square root of the delta-function but you won't be able to calculate with it. For example, you won't know what it evolves to. It's easy to see why. An ordinary delta-function evolves to the well-known nonzero functions at time $t$, calculable from the Green's functions. However, the square root of the delta-functions is proportional to delta-function but infinitely times smaller. So it will evolve into "zero" and unitarity will be violated, anyway. This is just not how the calcuations may be done.

Comment: @Lubos This is actually not correct.  You can show that $\delta ^2=\delta$, so that "$\sqrt{\delta}=\delta$".  I put this equation it quotes because I don't know anything about uniqueness of squaure-roots of nonnegative distributions.  The point is, there is at least *some* square-root of $\delta$, which is itself $\delta$.

Comment: Dear @Jonathan, your claim is obviously incorrect. $\delta^2(x)$ is much greater than $\delta(x)$. For example, you may write $\delta(x)=1/2\epsilon$ in the interval $(-\epsilon,+\epsilon)$. Its square is then $1/4\epsilon^2$ in the same interval and it doesn't integrate to one but to $1/2\epsilon$. That's no coincidence: $\int_{-\infty}^\infty dx\,f(x)\delta(x) = f(0)$, so if you substitute $f(x)=\delta(x)$ to integrate $\delta^2$, you get $\delta(0)$ on the right hand side which is definitely not one as it should be for the integral of $\delta(x)$ but a divergent constant.

Comment: @LubošMotl You argument does not make mathematical sense because you are treating $\delta$ as if it were a function.  As I said before, the correct way to define the product of two tempered distributions is as the Fourier Transform of the convolution of the Inverse Fourier Transforms.  With this definition, for $f$ Schwartz, $\langle \delta ^2|f\rangle =f(0)$, so that $\delta ^2=\delta$.

Comment: By the way, I think this is the perfect example of how mathematical rigor can *add* to the techniques of theoretical physics instead of *hidering* them, as it seems some physicists believe.  There is certainly a difference between being *rigorous* and being *pedantic*.  Rigor helps.  Pedantry doesn't.

Comment: Here's the computation:
$\langle \delta ^2|f\rangle =\langle \widehat{\check{\delta}\ast \check{\delta}}|f\rangle =\langle \check{\delta}\ast \check{\delta}|\hat{f}\rangle =\int \check{\delta}(x)\int \check{\delta}(y)\hat{f}(x+y)dydx=\int \check{\delta}(x)\int \delta(y)\hat{f}\left( x+\check{y}\right) dydx=\int \check{\delta}(x)\hat{g}(x,\check{0})=\hat{g}(\check{0},\check{0})=g(0,0)=f(0)$, where we have defined $g(x,y)=f(x+y)$ so that the notation was more understandable.

Comment: The "calculation" you wrote is completely nonsensical, Jonathan. $\delta(x)$ is still a function of one variable – or, in your completely needlessly nitpicking terminology (it's the point of such distributions that one CAN treat them as functions), a distribution acting on the space of functions of a single variable. You are confusing $[\delta(x)]^2$ which I proved is something else than $\delta(x)$ and ill-behaved even though both are functions/distributions of one variable that vanish outside $x=0$ with $\delta^{(2)}(x,y)=\delta(x)\delta(y)$ which waits to be integrated over two variables.

Comment: The question is what and when does the probabilistic "random" part of quantum mechanics then occur? When exactly is a random position generated from the probability? We observe a random result distributed with the probability, where does the "random number generator", so to speak, interject to produce this random result physically? What _is_ that random number generator? If not some special "collapse" process, then what? After all we see it, so it must be physical. (That is, the production of a random number from our detector for the position, whether "wave function collapse" is or not.)

Comment: If the outcome isn't determine with certainty, the random generator produces the outcome at the moment of the measurement. One may prove that every theory that would have some fabricated "random" results before the measurement would be inconsistent, see e.g. the free will theorem by Conway and Kochen. There is no "deconstruction" of the random generator. The probabilities predicted by quantum mechanics are the most fundamental numbers that follow from the physical theory, and everything else is on the contrary made of them.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what would be an answer to the *why* question. I can only comment on the known structure of the measurement as a operator.

Operators of a Hillbert space take vectors into vectors; they are an endomorphism of the Hillbert space. When you take a single measurement of a observable on a arbitrary vector, you obtain a random eigenvector of the observable. This is, conventionally speaking, a mapping between a vector and a vector. However the mapping is not deterministic, so there is not a single operator. In fact, there is one such operator for each eigenstate. They are better known as *projection operators*:

$$ M_{i} = | \psi_{i} \rangle \langle \psi_{i} |$$

When a measurement "happens" we can a posteriori state what specific projection operator took place on the system. We cannot use the operator formalism to describe the overall process in general.

Well, not quite. We have a formalism to describe classical probabilities distributions; its called mixed states. Mixed states are anything that is not a pure state, which can always be described with a density matrix whose entries are of the following form factor:

$$ \rho_{ij} = \psi_{i} \psi^{*}_{j} $$

as a density matrix, a classical probability distribution is seen as a purely diagonal matrix, whose entries are the probabilities of each eigenstate

so a measurement can be seen as the following map:

$$ \psi_{i} \psi_{j}^{*} \longrightarrow \psi_{i} \psi_{j}^{*} \delta_{ij} $$

So what  the measurement does in general is kill all off-diagonal components of the density matrix, and only leave the diagonal, that represent classical, actual probabilities.

Even if this map is not linear (as clearly stated by @Lubos), it preserves the trace of the density matrix. In other words, even if its not unitary, it is still a isometric transformation.

Comment: "So what the measurement does in general is kill all off-diagonal components of the density matrix": you wanted to say "So what decoherence does...", right? Your description of what measurement does isn't valid. The measurement, as understood in the incorrect interpretation of QM that you're promoting here, is not only bringing the density matrix to a diagonal form: it also sets to zero all the diagonal entries except for the chosen one.

Comment: Because the text of your answer makes it clear that you actually don't want to pick the "measured outcome" or explain how it is done - you're really trying to explain decoherence and not collapse (which is why your answer has no relevance to the original question which was about the collapse, but let's discuss your answer anyway) - you're talking about decoherence. But decoherence produces a map on the space of density matrices, not on the Hilbert space only.

Comment: So it makes no sense to ask whether this operation (elimination of off-diag. entries) is an isometry on the Hilbert space itself: it's not a map on the Hilbert space at all, it's a map on the space of density matrices (roughly speaking the tensor product of the Hilbert space and its conjugate copy) only. And on this space, the elimination of the off-diagonal elements is clearly not an isometry, either. So whatever way you look at your statements about the collapse's being an "isometry", they're invalid.

Comment: To show that the "decoherence map" (elimination of off-diagonal entries) isn't an isometry on the space of matrices, just consider what this map does with matrices $((a,b),(b,c))$ for different values of $b$. These matrices are clearly very far from each other in the natural metric on the space of matrices, especially if you pick a large $b$. But all these matrices get mapped to $((a,0),(0,b))$ so the distance of the values of the map is zero. ;-)

Comment: the question is about measurements on the global state vector of a system, the outcome is by definition isometric (the final state has the same norm as the original state vector)

Comment: This is a meaningless statement, lurscher. Of course that if you want to imagine that there exists a non-existent, non-local, inconsistent, non-unitary operation that messes up the wave function, you follow this pathological procedure at least by another procedure that rescales the wave function so that it has the same norm as before. But this is by additional fudging: there's no inherent preservation of the norm in the operation. It's wrong to say it's by "definition". By the most natural definition, the pathological non-unitary non-local operation you propose also modifies the norm.